# Dynamic Struct Variable Name

Tags: ios, swift, struct, alias

I define a struct as follows:

```
struct MyModel : Decodable {
   var id : Int
   var amount: Int
   let myNewTableId : Int
   let userId : Int 
   let myNewTable : MyNewTable
}
```

I then use this struct to convert JSON data into an object using `JSONDecoder().decode`.

The problem is that the `myNewTable` part of `myNewTableId` and `myNewTable` are based on an alias given to the SQL table they originate from. So if the alias is `abc` the fields should be `abcId` and `abc` and if its `def` it should be `defId` and `def`. I've saved this alias into a variable:

```
let MY_NEW_TABLE_ALIAS = "myNewT"
```

Is there a way to construct the variable names in the struct dynamically using `MY_NEW_TABLE_ALIAS`. Ideally, when the alias changes on the SQL side, I just want to update one variable, instead of having to update every single struct which uses that table.

Comment: You cannot create structs with dynamic variable names but you could apply a custom key decoding strategy to strip the alias.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to convert the json first to a string and replace occurrences with the needed key / use CodingKeys and make the struct as it is , btw you can't have dynamic variable names